# Canvas layering

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I am currently working on a project that similar to http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA9#under-the-hood using Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3. I manage to create the slider effect and adding the plus button to the multi layers of canvas (4 layers: the bottom image, the top image, the text display and the arrow slider). My problem is the mouse over for the plus button and displaying the text layer. I need to access the bottom layer to access the plus sign. How can I accomplish this? I am completely new at Javascript and HTML5.

HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="arrow_container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <div id="arrow_button" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="text_box"></span>
    <canvas id="top_canvas" onmouseover="displayInfo(event)"><img id="img_top" src="images/Technical_ONE_front.jpg" alt="device" /></canvas>
    <canvas id="plus_canvas"><img id="img_plus" src="images/Plus.png" alt="plus" /></canvas>
    <img id="img_bottom" src="images/Technical_ONE_back.jpg" alt="skeleton" />
</div>
```

Javascript init code:

```
$("#arrow_button").css({"position":"relative", "top":"730px", "left":"497px"});
$("#top_canvas").css({"top":"5px"});

var canvas = document.getElementById( "top_canvas" );
var plus_canvas = document.getElementById( "plus_canvas" );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var plus_ctx = plus_canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var top_img = document.getElementById( "img_top" );
var bottom_img = document.getElementById( "img_bottom" );
var plus_img = document.getElementById( "img_plus" );

canvas.width = plus_canvas.width = top_img.width;
canvas.height = plus_canvas.height = top_img.height;

ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
plus_ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillRect( canvas.width / 2, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
plus_ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, plus_canvas.width, plus_canvas.height );

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);

plus_ctx.beginPath();
plus_ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
plus_ctx.lineTo(0, plus_canvas.height);
plus_ctx.lineTo(plus_canvas.width, plus_canvas.height);
plus_ctx.lineTo(plus_canvas.width, 0);

ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage( top_img, 0, 0 );
plus_ctx.drawImage( bottom_img, 0, 0 );

for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  if( i == 0 ){
      plus_ctx.drawImage( plus_img, 511, 344 );
  } else if( i == 1 ){
      plus_ctx.drawImage( plus_img, 360, 348 );
  } else if( i == 2 ){
      plus_ctx.drawImage( plus_img, 501, 621 );
  }
}
```

Javascript displayInfo code:

```
var highlight_one = new Image();
var highlight_two = new Image();
var highlight_sound = new Image();

highlight_one.src = "../images/Highlight_one_over.png";
highlight_two.src = "../images/Highlight_two_over.png";
highlight_sound.src = "../images/Highlight_sound_over.png";

init();
    if( e.clientX >= 511 && e.clientX <= 526 && e.clientY >= 344 && e.clientY <= 359 ){
        plus_ctx.drawImage( highlight_one, 0, 0 );
        html = "<p>Blah Blah Blah</p>";
    } else if( e.clientX >= 360 && e.clientX <= 375 && e.clientY >= 348 && e.clientY <= 363 ) {
        plus_ctx.drawImage( highlight_sound, 0, 0 );
        html = "<p>La Di Da</p>";
    } else if( e.clientX >= 501 && e.clientX <= 516 && e.clientY >= 621 && e.clientY <= 336 ) {
        plus_ctx.drawImage( highlight_two, 0, 0 );
        html = "<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>";
    }

    $('.text_box').html(html);
```

CSS code:

```
* {margin:0}
#container{width:1024px; height:768px; position:relative}
#img_top, #top_canvas{position:absolute; z-index:3}
#img_plus, #plus_canvas{position:absolute; z-index:1}
#img_bottom, #img_top{width:1024px; height:768px}
.text_box{top:0; left:0; width:1024px; height:768px; padding:20px; position:absolute; z-index:2}
#arrow_container{position:absolute; width:1024px; height:768px; top:0; z-index:4}
#arrow_button{width:30px; height:30px; background-image:url("../images/arrows.png")}
```

The image size is fixed to 1024px by 768 px.

Comment: Place the image tags outside of the canvas tags and try to create and position them using jquery and css. Maybe you have to clarify the question a bit to make sure people get what you are trying to do.

Comment: In the example, it displays the information when you roll over the plus button. I separated all my components into 4 layers. The most bottom layer is the background image and the plus buttons. I want to create the same effect from the example to those buttons and display the information in the text area layer which is the third layer from the bottom. My problem is I cannot access the buttons because the other layers overlay the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by tracking the position of your mouse with respect to the entire page:

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
}
```

And comparing that to the position of your buttons by, first, determining where the arrows are:

```
var whereIsMyArrow = $('#arrow').offset();
```

And then conditioning a behavior when the mouse is on top of the arrow:

```
if ((mouseX>=whereIsMyArrow.left)&&<br>(mouseX<=(whereIsMyArrow.left+$('#arrow').width())&&
   (mouseY>=whereIsMyArrow.top)&&<br>(mouseY<=(whereIsMyArrow.top+$('#arrow').height())){
   //do something
}
```

Make sure that the conditional is inside the .mousemove(e) event.

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent layer on top and add event handlers for it.